# What is a clean way to check for a param that is equal to null in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am passing some form values from React to a Node/Express backend, in the node backend I am trying to return an error if a null param is passed.

For ex the query string might be
http://localhost:3000/api/processFlights?type=return&departureDate=11-11-11&returnDate=null

Doing (!returnDate) in my express code isn't working because it thinks null is a string.

So basically do I have any option beside (returnDate !=== 'null')?

Comment: Yes, the value is `"null"` (a string) so if that's what you want to check for, you have to compare to the string `"null"`.

Comment: You could also write your own middleware that would turn any `req.param` property with the value of `"null"` into the actual `null` and then you could use `if (!req.param.returnDate) {...}`.